# Gold Lamé swimsuit, / Asthmatic dad's dead. / Sorry Luke, she's your sister

Tags: knowledge, movies, poetry, haiku

Guess the movie (or movie series):

> Gold Lamé swimsuit,
>   Asthmatic dad's dead.
>   Sorry Luke, she's your sister.
>
> Plagued by movie curse,
>   Odd-numbered installments bad.
>   Is Vger God? No.
>
> Strangely therapist
>   Doesn't know he's dead.
>   The kind of thing you'd notice.
>
> Extremely cheap Snape
>   Robs Nakatomi Plaza.
>   Bruce in vest and socks.
>
> You should always choose
>   The lesser of two weevils.
>   Surprise!
>
> Rainy and muddy.
>   But you can't live on millet.
>   The farmers have won.
>
> Theme park power fail
>   Destruction ensues
>   As large T. Rex runs amok.
>
> Theme park power fail
>   Destruction ensues
>   As Yul Brynner runs amok.
>
> Short-arsed Scientologist,
>   Confidence crisis.
>   The pattern is full.
>
> We deal in lead, friend.
>   We're in the same business, eh?
>   Farmers win again.
>
> Nuke it from orbit.
>   Get away from her, you bitch!
>   Costaguano?

Comment: Nice except for the spoiler.

Comment: @dennisdeems, they're only spoilers if you know the answers. ;)

Comment: Gold Lamé swimsuit XD

Comment: Technically a bikini but that has too many syllables.

Comment: How about Gold Lamé Two-piece?

Comment: That would work.

Comment: "Sorry Luke, she's your sister." LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Gold Lamé swimsuit,
Asthmatic dad's dead.
Sorry Luke, she's your sister.
```

> Star Wars

```
Plagued by movie curse,
Odd-numbered installments bad.
Is Vger God? No.
```

> Star Trek

```
Strangely therapist
Doesn't know he's dead.
The kind of thing you'd notice.
```

> Sixth Sense

```
Extremely cheap Snape
Robs Nakatomi Plaza.
Bruce in vest and socks.
```

> Die Hard

```
You should always choose
The lesser of two weevils.
Surprise!
```

> Master and Commander

```
Rainy and muddy.
But you can't live on millet.
The farmers have won.
```

> Seven Samurai (thanks Zfrisch)

```
Theme park power fail
Destruction ensues
As large T. Rex runs amok.
```

> Jurassic Park

```
Theme park power fail
Destruction ensues
As Yul Brynner runs amok.
```

> Westworld

```
Short-arsed Scientologist,
Confidence crisis.
The pattern is full.
```

> Top Gun

```
We deal in lead, friend.
We're in the same business, eh?
Farmers win again.
```

> The Magnificent Seven

```
Nuke it from orbit.
Get away from her, you bitch!
Costaguano?
```

> Aliens

Comment: The one you're missing I believe is the Seven Samurai. http://www.willamette.edu/~rloftus/jfilm/sevendamdisc.html

Comment: @zfrisch Yep - that looks good, thanks